# Does counter_cache only get triggered for create & destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Lets say I change an association in my `Comment` model via - Comment.find(20).update(post_id: 30)

So in this case would the counter cache be decremented for the `Post` model?

Comment: Yes,the count decreases for previous and increments for updated post.

Comment: In my experience, the `counter_cache` column is super weak. It will go into negative values if you remove records manually (IE during testing). It's crazy ineffective